# ASP.NET Core MVC - parameter at URL

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, razor-pages, asp.net-core-8

I want to add a `returnURL` parameter like sample below, this will trigger JS toaster.

```
localhost/Account/Login
localhost/Account/Login?returnURL=Forbidden
```

This parameter is receiving "/" and therefore showing `?returnURL=%2F`, and I'm not finding a way to achieve the expected behavior (remove it when not needed). I'm running ASP.NET Core 8 MVC project with Razor views.

`Program.cs`:

```
app.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "default",
        pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}")
        .RequireAuthorization();
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Login(string returnURL = null)
{
    if (returnURL == "/")
        returnURL = null;

    ViewBag.returnURL = returnURL;

    return View();
}
```

Razor view:

```
<form asp-controller="Account"
      asp-action="Authentication"
      asp-route-returnURL="@viewBagVarName"
      method="post" id="form-login">
</form>
```

Comment: Can you explain more details about your question? What do you mean by trigger JS toaster?  Can not see any code using JS toaster in your example.  
Do you mean after setting the return url, it will trigger the JS toaster, and prevent the redirect to return url behavior, or you just want to use the JS toaster to display the returned url?